# Template-String to handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have converted my template strings to handlebars and now have places where i don't know how to solve this now. Can i solve this somehow with for or each?

Old:

```
<div class="importance">${"&#9733;".repeat(todo.prio)}</div> -->
```

New:

```
<div class="importance">{{prio}}</div>
```

Also i would like to add a class in the handlebar when the value is "done".

```
if(todo.state === 'erledigt'){
   document.getElementById(id).classList.add('done');
}
```

the todo.state was in the template string in my old code. now it is called {{state}}.

Comment: Is `prio` an array?